# how to substring input with various languages in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode

Given a string, it may contain english or japanese(wide chars) or other languages

How can I get the first char / substrings of this string?

ex: "Give" => "G"
    "日本" => "日"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is built in to ruby so long as you have the correct encoding set on your string:

```
$ ruby -ve 'p "日本".encoding, "日本"[0]'
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
"日"
```

There is no need to use mb_chars nor ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveSupport's [`Chars` class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html)

```
string = "日本"
string.mb_chars[0]
=> "日"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 'ActiveRecord', you can use mb_chars.

Or you can use the standard library:

```
str = '日本'
str.codepoints.take(1)
#日
```

'codepoint' gives an enumerator through the string's actual encodings and 'take' will take any amount of chars you want. Or you can use

```
str.codepoints.to_a[0]
```

It will convert the string's encodings to an array. It is good for short strings but not good for big ones.